# SpalshScreen into endless loop

Tags: java, android

i am working on an android app, and the splashscreen instead of loading the next activity, keeps on posting the toast and gets into endless loop! i am posting the required code and logcat here:

SplashScreen.java:

```
  package com.example.ambuj.supercabs;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.app.Activity;


  public class SplashScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

  private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIMER = 5000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Thread loading = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                Intent main = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,loginActivity.class);
                startActivity(main);
                finish();


            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };

    loading.start();
}


   /**new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,loginActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    },SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIMER);   }*/


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

this is loginActivity.java:

```
package com.example.ambuj.supercabs;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android .content.Context;


public class loginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Please fill your login details!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM,0,0);
    loginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    loginActivity.this.finish();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and this is my logcat:

```
01-24 12:44:34.050    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-24 12:44:34.050    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
01-24 12:44:34.160    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 114K, 10% free 16889K/18652K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
01-24 12:44:34.190    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 23.322MB for 5474752-byte allocation
01-24 12:44:34.205    7892-7902/com.example.ambuj.supercabs D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 22235K/24000K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-24 12:44:34.270    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs I/﹕ PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
01-24 12:44:34.285    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000
01-24 12:44:34.320    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-24 12:44:36.235    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-24 12:44:36.240    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
01-24 12:44:36.335    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-24 12:44:36.380    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-24 12:44:36.405    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-24 12:44:36.435    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-24 12:44:36.460    7892-7892/com.example.ambuj.supercabs W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
```

Comment: It goes into endless loop because you have an endless loop: from run you go to onCreate because you're starting the same activity again and then again into run.

Comment: @Alex, i did as the people suggested but sitll im facing the same bug, could you please edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
   package com.example.ambuj.supercabs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;


public class SplashScreen extends Activity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

Thread loading = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(2000);
            Intent main = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,loginActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
            finish();


        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

loading.start();
}
}
```

Comment: did as you said, but of no use, still the same error

Comment: please paste here your complete exception from logcat